# Unity: Best way to make interface in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

For my Android game I need to make a pop up interface window, which should appear when a level is complete. What is the best way to do so?

**UPDATE 2**: It works! The final version I used:

Scripts
[image]

Hierarchy
[image]

The only thing left is setting `Dialog` **game object** active, when the win condition is true. It is done in my `GameManager` **script**. Thus, in each scene I have to manually drag `Dialog` **object** onto `GameManager` **script**'s *Dialog variable*, so that it can alter `Dialog` **object**. I've tried to *Get (find)* the `Dialog` **object** in `GameManager`'s *Start()* method, but it can't be done, because `Dialog` **object** is inactive by default. Is there a way to find and link an inactive game object though scripting?

Comment: As far as I understand the thing you want to achieve is to have a WinPopUp dialog which can be reusable in different scenes. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. It is reusable, but when I instantiate it in another scene, each of its buttons requires manual resetting WinPopup object and functions in OnClick().

Comment: Does your onClick methods call function by other classes or only from class which is already a part of the dialog?

Comment: I suppose buttons call methods from other class...

Comment: If you want to call function from other classes you need to do it in a different way than assigning the functions dirrectly from Unity Editor. Maybe use Actions in order to achieve this.

Comment: You mean UnityAction, delegates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, since the thing which you want to achieve is to create a reusable dialog with buttons which will trigger different functions from other classes which are part of the current `Scene`,  the way you can achieve this is by using `UnityAction`.
Let's say you have a `Dialog` script with a function `OnButtonClickedAction` :

```
public class Dialog : MonoBehaviour {

public static UnityAction OnButtonClickedAction;

    public void OnButtonClicked(){
        if (OnButtonClickedAction != null){
            OnButtonClickedAction.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `Scene`'s where you want to show this dialog you should have a class which subscribes for those actions:

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnEnable() {
        Dialog.OnButtonClickedAction += CodeToRunOnButtonClick;
    }

    private void OnDisable(){
        Dialog.OnButtonClickedAction += CodeToRunOnButtonClick;
    }

    private void CodeToRunOnButtonClick(){
        // code
    }
}
```

And by doing this, your `Dialog` is reusable between different `Scene`'s.

There is another way using Singleton pattern, by calling a function from a `GameObject` which doesn't get destroyed during changing `Scene`'s. Let's say you have a `GameManager` class which doesn't get destroyed so you can call something like that from your `Dialog` script.

```
public class Dialog : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnButtonClicked(){
        GameManager.Instance.CodeToRunOnButtonClick();
    }
}
```

I prefer the first version, but it's up to you.

Here is the hierarchy inside Unity Editor:

[image]

As you can see there is a `Dialog` object inside the `Scene` which has the `Dialog` script attached to it and on `Button`'s `onClick` event, `Dialog`'s `OnButtonClicked` method is assigned.

And by adding `Script` object to every scene where you want to show this Dialog/WinPopUp you can listen for that action like this:

[image]

If you have more than one button, you can easily extend the `UnityAction` to support adding let's say an id to every `Button` (`buttonId`) and pass it like that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to try the first version, but I don't quite understand where exactly I should use the scripts you provided. Suppose, I have empty WinPopup and its child buttons, each of which should do its own action... To which of these obejcts do I attach the scripts and how to set proper action for buttons?

Comment: So WinPopup is `Dialog` and in all your button's onClick you should attack a function like `OnButtonClicked` from your WinPopup script.

Comment: And where do I attach "public class Script" you provided? I'm not so good at Events, but won't this event launch the same actions for each button?

Comment: `Script` should be attached to a `GameObject` which is inside your `Scene` where you want to shot the `Dialog`. And the functions and can be two, `FirstButtonClick` `SecondButtonClick` based on how many buttons you have.

Comment: Oh, gosh, this is confusing... Alright, I now have the "Script" script attached to Canvas, and "Dialog" script attached to WinPopup object. Script has functions for each button (i.e. "Restart" method, "NextLevel" method and so on). Now I use WinPopup (with Dialog attached) as a method source for each button, and set the corresponding method? I'm gonna update the question with screenshots

Comment: Ok, give me a little time to upload the solution as screenshots too

Comment: The answer is updated. Hope it's more understandable now

Comment: OH, so the `Script` script was supposed to be attached to a separate `Script` object! Now I see. And I think I thought up a way to implement your solution, taking into account multiple buttons/actions: instead of `buttonID` I'll pass a _string with method name_ to `CodeToRunOnButtonClick()`. And according to that string, `CodeToRunOnButtonClick()` will return the right method and pass it to the Event system, that will run it when the button is clicked. Gonna try it tomorrow and report back. Huge THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. Doesn't matter if you choose a string or int it's the same. I just think that the possibility for an typo in string is bigger than in using int.

Comment: I've got two more little questions, by your leave: How does the `Script` script knows about `Dialog.OnButtonClickedAction`? Shouldn't we have to have a **reference variable** and _Get_ the `Dialog` object/component? And the other question: CodeToRunOnButtonClick(), should it _return_ a function I need, or should it just _call_ the function?

Comment: Inside `Script`'s `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` you are subscribing and unsubscribing (to not leak) to `Dialog`'s `OnButtonClickAction`. By doing this you are 'listening' for that action to happen. `CodeToRunOnButtonClick` is the actual function you want to use. You can rename it, call another function and etc.

Comment: Oh gosh, IT WORKS! I'll update the question. The only thing left is setting `Dialog` **game object** active, when the win condition is true. It is done in my `GameManager` **script**. Thus, in each scene I have to manually drag `Dialog` **object** onto `GameManager` **script's _Dialog variable_**, so that it can alter `Dialog` **object**. I've tried to _Get (find)_ the `Dialog` **object** in `GameManager's` _Start()_ method, but it can't be done, because `Dialog` **object** is inactive when the scene starts. Is there a way to find and link an inactive game object though scripting?

Comment: Instead of adding the Dialog in every scene, you can create a Prefab and instantiate it everytime when you need it. You can create another script DialogHandler which is active in the scene and only takes care to holds an instance to the dialog, so the GameObject can access it. There are lots of ways to achieve this

Comment: Btw you should accept the answer if it's working for you : )

Comment: Yes, yes, sure, and I'm so very grateful for your help, this is something! Thank you!

Comment: I'll try making Canvas prefab and Dialog prefab separately, so that GameManager could use Dialog Prefab in Dialog box. And in the scene I would add Canvas separately, and add Dialog as a child.

Comment: Nah, for some reason `GameManager` **object** still requires manual resetting `Dialog` **object** to show it `if (win)`. Despite I've made a Prefab out of `Dialog` **object** and set it up in `GameManager prefab`'s Dialog field...

Comment: Aight, I'll do it manually. It takes only 5 seconds so... Nothing serious

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for non-functional buttons may be lack of the event system on scene. Event system positioned under UI section, in the same place Canvas is. It is added automatically when you create the first UI element on stage.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/EventSystem.html